# Planning time for partition table is taking more time in postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-11

I have less than 200 partitions(Daily partitions) and each partition with 5M+ records.

When I pass one day data with direct partition I see estimated plan 0.01ms but while using parent table 190ms(too much). Only difference observed is Append in plan.

Can we eliminate **Append** or reduce **pruning** time in postgres 11?

QUERY:

```
explain (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, COSTS, BUFFERS, TIMING,SUMMARY) select 1 from test WHERE date1 >'2021-01-27 13:41:26' and date1<'2021-01-27 21:41:26' and own=123 and mob=123454234

----------------------------plan-----------

Append (cost=0.12..4.19 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=0 loops=1) 
  Buffers: shared hit=1 
  -> Index Only Scan using test_20210127_pkey on test_20210127 (cost=0.12..4.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=1) 
     Output: 1 
     Index Cond: ((test_20210127.date1 > '2021-01-27 13:41:26'::timestamp without time zone) AND (test_20210127.date1 < '2021-01-27 21:41:26'::timestamp without time zone) AND (test_20210127.own = 123) AND (test_20210127.mob = 123454234)) 
     Heap Fetches: 0 
     Buffers: shared hit=1 
Planning Time: 190.440 ms 
Execution Time: 0.093 ms
```

------------Snipped table structure----

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    own integer NOT NULL,
    mob bigint NOT NULL,  
    date1 timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,    
    ver integer NOT NULL,
    c5
    ...
    c100
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (date1, own, mob, ver)
        USING INDEX TABLESPACE tb_1
) PARTITION BY RANGE (date1) 
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE tb_1;
 

-- Partitions SQL

CREATE TABLE public.test_20211003 PARTITION OF public.test
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-10-03 00:00:00') TO ('2020-10-04 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE public.test_201004 PARTITION OF public.test
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2020-10-04 00:00:00') TO ('2020-10-05 00:00:00');

  ........6 months partitions
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. For future questions, please make sure you paste the execution plan "as is" without messing with line breaks and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Otherwise it's unreadable

Comment: Why do you use daily partitioning with only 5 million records a day? With this amount of data, I would use a minimum of a monthly partition. That would give you just 7 partitions for 200 days and might improve the planning time.

Comment: Only I will keep 6 months data ,So we can drop old partitions right?

Comment: Including a timestamp in a primary key seems rather strange given the resolution of a timestamp. I understand that it's caused by the fact that Postgres has no global indexes, but still... Does the planning time change if you remove the primary key?

Comment: Without PK also same issue @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Well, the best solution is to upgrade to 12 or 13 - planning time is about 4ms with 600 partitions (on my laptop with Windows 10, and even less if the partition information is in the cache). If this is is so important then you should make upgrading "possible"

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to a later PostgreSQL version, as there were performance improvements in v12.

But if query execution time is short, planning time will always dominate. You can test a prepared statement, but I doubt that runtime partition pruning will be so much faster.

Essentially, the worse query performance is the expected price you are paying for the benefit of a simple way to discard old data.

Comment: Thanks for Answer @Laurenz Albe.  But  migration to 12 not possible now.i tried with prepared statement too but no use. At least I want bring down to less than 40 ms .Any suggestion in parameter setting changes.

Comment: No; you will have to live with it. The only remedy would be to select from the partition directly - but if you first have to figure out which partition it is, that will probably take at least as long as partition pruning.

Comment: Why append(in plan) is coming in one partition filter ,if it more than 1(If we filter more than 1 date partition) Append make sense right?.

Comment: That is superfluous, but does not harm. As you see, it takes 0.001 milliseconds.